# Android. Воспроизведение текста голосом

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Сталкивался ли кто-то с этой задачей ? Есть ли библиотеки или решения ?

Comment: Это называется `Text To Speach`, сокращенно TTS https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20tts%20library&es_th=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй андроидовскую библиотеку `android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;`, Хороший пример почитай [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/224685/)